# Wordpress: Restrict specific user to manages posts in specific category

Tags: wordpress, permissions, authorization, categories, capability

I explain this with an example. In my blog I have 2 users:

- John
- Paul

that write posts. Posts have 2 categories (to be precise, it's a custom taxonomy):

- Cats
- Dogs

John manages the Cats section of the blog and Paul manages the Dogs. So I want John to be able only to view/add/edit posts in "Cats" category and the same for Paul.

How can do this (preferably without the use of a plugin)?